# Changing numbers for given indices between matrices

Tags: matlab

I'm struggling with one of my matlab assignments. I want to create 10 different models. Each of them is based on the same original array of dimensions 1x100 m_est. Then with for loop I am choosing 5 random values from the original model and want to add the same random value to each of them. The cycle repeats 10 times chosing different values each time and adding different random number. Here is a part of my code:

```
steps=10;

for s=1:steps

    for i=1:1:5
        rl(s,i)=m_est(randi(numel(m_est))); 
        rl_nr(s,i)=find(rl(s,i)==m_est);
        a=-1;
        b=1;
        r(s)=(b-a)*rand(1,1)+a; 
    end
    pert_layers(s,:)=rl(s,:)+r(s); 
    M=repmat(m_est',s,1); 

end

for k=steps
    for m=1:1:5
        M_pert=M;
        M_pert(1:k,rl_nr(k,1:m))=pert_layers(1:k,1:m);
    end
end
```

In matrix M I am storing 10 initial models and want to replace the random numbers with indices from rl_nr matrix into those stored in pert_layers matrix. However, the last loop responsible for assigning values from pert_layers to rl_nr indices does not work properly.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Best regards

Comment: Well, the last loop causes the problem. I cant figure it out how to  write this line properly: M_pert(1:k,rl_nr(k,1:m))=pert_layers(1:k,1:m); because matlab seems to either change indices only from the first array of rl_nr or pick them randomly. I want the program to assign the value from pert_layers onto the rl_nr index and put it into M_pert matrix. I hope thats explains clearly my intentions.

Comment: Minor note.  In your last `for` loop, `M_pert` keeps getting reinitialized, so it will only remember the change made in the last iteration of that loop.  However, I'm writing an answer that's more vectorized, so stay tuned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses a lot of loops and in this particular circumstance, it's quite inefficient.  It's better if you actually vectorize your code.  As such, let me go through your problem description one point at a time and let's code up each part (if applicable):

> I want to create 10 different models. Each of them is based on the same original array of dimensions 1x100 m_est.

I'm interpreting this as you having an array `m_est` of 100 elements, and with this array, you wish to create 10 different "models", where each model is 5 elements sampled from `m_est`.  `rl` will store these values from `m_est` while `rl_nr` will store the **indices / locations** of where these values originated from.  Also, for each model, you wish to add a random value to every element that is part of this model.

> Then with for loop I am choosing 5 random values from the original model and want to add the same random value to each of them.

Instead of doing this with a `for` loop, generate all of your random indices in one go.    Since you have 10 steps, and we wish to sample 5 points per step, you have `10*5 = 50` points in total.  As such, why don't you use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) instead? `randperm` is exactly what you're looking for, and we can use this to generate unique random indices so that we can ultimately use this to sample from `m_est`.  `randperm` generates a vector from `1` to `N` but returns a random permutation of these elements.  This way, you only get numbers enumerated from `1` to `N` exactly once and we will ensure no repeats.  As such, simply use `randperm` to generate 50 elements, then reshape this array into a matrix of size `10 x 5`, where the number of rows tells you the number of steps you want, while the number of columns is the total number of points per model.  Therefore, do something like this:

```
num_steps = 10;
num_points_model = 5;
ind = randperm(numel(m_est));
ind = ind(1:num_steps*num_points_model);
rl_nr = reshape(ind, num_steps, num_points_model);
rl = m_est(rl_nr);
```

The first two lines are pretty straight forward.  We are just declaring the total number of steps you want to take, as well as the total number of points per model.  Next, what we will do is generate a random permutation of length 100, where elements are enumerated from 1 to 100, but they are in random order.  You'll notice that this random vector uses only a value within the range of 1 to 100 **exactly** once.  Because you only want to get 50 points in total, simply subset this vector so that we only get the first 50 random indices generated from `randperm`.  These random indices get stored in `ind`.

Next, we simply reshape `ind` into a `10 x 5` matrix to get `rl_nr`.  `rl_nr` will contain those indices that will be used to select those entries from `m_est` which is of size `10 x 5`.  Finally, `rl` will be a matrix of the same size as `rl_nr`, but it will contain the actual random values sampled from `m_est`.  These random values correspond to those indices generated from `rl_nr`.

Now, the final step would be to add the same random number to each model.  You can certainly use `repmat` to replicate a random column vector of 10 elements long, and duplicate them 5 times so that we have 5 columns then add this matrix together with `rl`.... so something like:

```
a = -1;
b = 1;
r = (b-a)*rand(num_steps, 1) + a;
r = repmat(r, 1, num_points_model);
M_pert = rl + r;
```

Now `M_pert` is the final result you want, where we take each model that is stored in `rl` and add the same random value to each corresponding model in the matrix.  However, if I can suggest something more efficient, I would suggest you use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) instead, which does this replication under the hood.  Essentially, the above code would be replaced with:

```
a = -1;
b = 1;
r = (b-a)*rand(num_steps, 1) + a;
M_pert = bsxfun(@plus, rl, r);
```

Much easier to read, and less code.  `M_pert` will contain your models in each row, with the same random value added to each particular model.

> The cycle repeats 10 times chosing different values each time and adding different random number.

Already done in the above steps.

---

I hope you didn't find it an imposition to completely rewrite your code so that it's more vectorized, but I think this was a great opportunity to show you some of the more advanced functions that MATLAB has to offer, as well as more efficient ways to generate your random values, rather than looping and generating the values one at a time.

Hopefully this will get you started.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm really glad to hear that elaborated answer. I know that my coding is a little bit archaic since I havent been using matlab in a while. But my main problem was the final stage (the last `for` loop) of the model creation. So the main idea is to to create 10 models based on original `m_est` which I made by creating M matrix which looks like this `M=repmat(m_est',num_steps,1)`. And now the tricky part is to replace the values in `M` under the locations of `rl_nr` with those stored in `rl`. So generally speaking, put matrix `rl` into locations `rl_nr` of `M`. Once again thanks for the response.

Comment: @Pawel - I don't quite understand what's going on in that line of code, so I can't really provide an answer.  My apologies.

Comment: Okey, lets say we have a model `m_est=(1,100)` with some measurement data. And my task is to pick random locations in the matrix and add to values in those locations the same number (in this case it is random as well). Hence, it is all about adding a constant/same number to random locations in my model `m_est`. I know this might sound strange. I thought about `M(rl_nr)=rl` but it doesn't work...

Comment: @Pawel - OK, well in my answer to you I did do that.... however, to get it to work with your last `for` loop... I'm having a bit of trouble.  I'll think about it, but you should probably consider going the vectorized way rather than sticking with your multiple `for` loops IMHO.

Comment: I have created sth like this to generate the last step: `M=repmat(m_est',num_steps,1);
M(1,(rl_nr(1,:)))=M_pert(1,:);` of course it works just for the first row of M and here I would use `for` loop but as you have mentioned before it keeps reinitialize and I get only the last row of `rl` into matrix `M`. Do you know how to fix it? As for the vectorized approach I would probably have to incorporate somehow `num_steps` into `M(1,(rl_nr(1,:)))=M_pert(1,:);` but I must say that I have no idea how.

Comment: Dear @rayryeng, could you please help me with this last step because I don't quite understand why it doesn't work. This is my idea: `M=repmat(m_est',num_steps,1);
for t=5
    for s=1:10
        M(s,rl_nr(s,t))=M_pert(s,t);
    end  
end` I want the loop to enter `M` matrix index which is stored in `rl_nr` and replace its value with the one stored in `rl`. However, it replaces values of indexes only from the last column of `rl_nr`. I have really spent some time on it and would appreciate any hint why the loop remembers only the last iteration. Once again thank you for the time you have devoted.

Comment: @Pawel check your loop with the variable t. It only uses index 5. Change that to 1:5.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't notice simple errors when I'm sitting too much on a problem;) I will definitely use vectorized approach in the future.